# Derivative property of Bilateral Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

According to the definition of the bilateral Laplace Transform:
$$ X(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)e^{-st}dt$$
where $s=\sigma+i\omega$.
So to get the derivative property, $y(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$:
$$Y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}e^{-st}dt $$ and using integration by parts we get:
$$ Y(s)= x(t)e^{-st}\bigr|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \ -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-se^{-st}x(t)dt \ =x(t)e^{-st}\bigr|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} +sX(s)
$$

**Question:** How can one get rid of the first term? Since the correct answer is just the other term.

Comment: it is because $x(t) e^{-\sigma t}$ is assumed to be $\in L^1$ (the integrals converge absolutely) so that $|x(t_n) e^{-s{t_n}}| \to 0$ for some sequences $t_n \to +\infty, T_n \to -\infty$, and since $X(s) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{T_n}^{t_n} x(t) e^{-st} dt$ everything works well

Comment: note that the bilateral Laplace transform (at first) is well defined only if $x(t) e^{-\sigma t} \in L^1$ for $\sigma \in (a,b)$, so that $X(s)$ is analytic for $Re(s) \in (a,b)$, this is different from the Fourier transform which doesn't require that $x(t) \in L^1$ or that the Fourier transform of $x(t) e^{-\sigma t}$ is well-defined for any $\sigma \ne 0$